# Start Zathura full-screen / remember window size

Tags: xfce, zathura

How do I start the document viewer [Zathura](https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/) maximised?

Is there any way to get my window manager `xfce` to remember the last open window's size?

The default window size is only about 1/8th of my screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set height and width to a large value, so that it will cover your entire screen. In my case the following did the trick:

> set window-height 3000
>    set window-width 3000

Answer (score 7):

There's an undocumented launch option, `--mode`. The examples given for this were "presentation", and "fullscreen", so just use `zathura --mode fullscreen [FILE]`.
If that gets to be a bother, they don't have a configuration entry for this, for whatever reason, so what I did was add `--mode fullscreen` to my zathura.desktop file. It's a bit of a bother having to use xdg-open to access all of my PDFs, though.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `zathurarc` to configure the default window size. From `man zathurarc`:

```
window-height
   Defines the window height on startup

   · Value type: Integer

   · Default value: 600

window-width
   Defines the window width on startup

   · Value type: Integer

   · Default value: 800
```

Comment: for info: zathura looks for `zathurarc` at  `/etc/zathurarc` or `~/.config/zathura/zathurac` by default https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/documentation/

Comment: Docs https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-zathurarc/#lbDE