# Maximize zathura

Tags: zathura

How can I maximize zathura document viewer from the configuration? I've been looking at different resource files, but most people set the window height and width. I don't know why nobody maximizes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it!
[askubuntu/How do I launch zathura from bash/emacs maximized/fullscreen](https://askubuntu.com/a/1065086/334407)

> `--mode fullscreen`. It isn't in the man file, for whatever reason.

[unix.stackexchange/Start Zathura full-screen / remember window size](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/462383/96101)

> There's an undocumented launch option, --mode. The examples given for
> this were "presentation", and "fullscreen", so just use zathura --mode
> fullscreen [FILE]. If that gets to be a bother, they don't have a
> configuration entry for this, for whatever reason, so what I did was
> add --mode fullscreen to my zathura.desktop file. It's a bit of a
> bother having to use xdg-open to access all of my PDFs, though.

Also,

> You can set height and width to a large value, so that it will cover
> your entire screen. In my case the following did the trick:
>
> ```
> set window-height 3000
> set window-width 3000
> ```

I also found interesting from [bbs.archlinux/Open file without program name](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=97343):

```
function o() {
    xdg-open "$@" 2> /dev/null
}
```

After making zathura the preferred aplication, modifying `/usr/share/applications/org.pwmt.zathura.desktop` file to include `--mode fullscreen` in the exec line, and adding that function to the shell configuration, you should be able to open zathura in fullscreen mode with `o name.pdf`.